# What is a Good Procedure for Syncing Branched Files To Their Trunk Location For Testing in Perforce?

Tags: perforce

Apologies if the name of the question is confusing.

I'm a bit new to version control (sadly) and feel like I'm not using things in the right way, so I've come for some help.

Basically, my situation is that I have two files I've branched off the trunk and edited. The changes in those files are pretty big, so they are to be thoroughly tested on staging before being pushed to production. What I'm confused about is how to sync them into staging if the client view there is the trunk itself. I can't modify the client view to sync from my branch since the sync has to occur from a specific account used by my entire group. Is there a way to say "sync from..." or something along those lines, in a command? Maybe specify a new client view inside of the sync statement?

Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the "account" in your description. `client`, `user`?

I guess that in the long term you will have to relinquish the constraint that "into staging ... the client view there is the trunk itself". If you do development in branches, and then integrate them back into the trunk after testing, you'll need to be able to use the test environment on some development branch.

Anyway:

```
p4 help sync
p4 help usage

p4 -c STAGING sync //...
```